# why am i not getting print message?

Tags: python, printing, pygame

```
 while running:
        screen.fill((255,255,255))

        screen.blit(background,(0,0))   
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False


# keystroke controlling   i am not getting this print message 

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    print("space is pressed ")

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    print("released")
                                 
        
        playerx += playerx_change
        player(playerx , playery)
        cactus(cactusx , cactusy)
        pygame.display.update()

game()
```

Comment: The event.type can't be KEYUP and K_SPACE at the same time

Comment: You have to use `event.key == pygame.K_SPACE` instead of  `event.type == pygame.K_SPACE`

Answer (score 2):

This is because event.type cannot be KEYUP AND K_SPACE  at the same time .
Rewrite the code as :

```
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    print("space is pressed ")

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                    print("released")
```